# Unable to get module to publish correctly with PyPi

Tags: python, pypi

I'm attempting to publish my module to PyPi but I'm running into troubles. It publishes, and I can install it via Pip, but I cannot seem to figure out the correct import statement to instantiate my class.

This is my `setup.py` file, the code lives in `discord_webhooks.py` within the same directory. [Here's the published package](https://pypi.org/project/Discord-Webhooks/).

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

long_description = open('README.md').read()

    setup(
      name='Discord Webhooks',
      version='1.0.1',
      packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests', 'tests.*']),
      url='https://github.com/JamesIves/discord-webhooks',
      author='James Ives',
      author_email='iam@jamesiv.es',
      description='Easy to use package for Python which allows for sending of webhooks to a Discord server.',
      long_description=long_description,
      license='MIT',
      install_requires=[
        'requests==2.20.0'
      ],
      classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3'
      ],
    )
```

I've attempted `import DiscordWebhooks`, and `from discord_webhooks import DiscordWebhooks` after doing `pip install discord-webhooks` but neither seem to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: From the Git repo it looks like you don't have a sub-directory for the code. I followed the directory structure used here and it worked for me: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: Is there an alternative package definition for single file modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this one on my own. As this is a single file module I need to use `py_modules` inside of the `setup.py` file.

Here's the updated file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

long_description = open('README.md').read()

setup(
  name='Discord Webhooks',
  version='1.0.3',
  py_modules=['discord_webhooks'],
  url='https://github.com/JamesIves/discord-webhooks',
  author='James Ives',
  author_email='iam@jamesiv.es',
  description='Easy to use package for Python which allows for sending of webhooks to a Discord server.',
  long_description=long_description,
  license='MIT',
  install_requires=[
    'requests==2.20.0'
  ],
  classifiers=[
    'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
    'Environment :: Other Environment',
    'Intended Audience :: Developers',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
  ],
)
```